# When I use libvirt api to migration,occur a error like this

Tags: migration, kvm, libvirt

libvirt.libvirtError: unable to connect to server at 'ccrfox112:49152': Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

When migrating QEMU guests, without tunnelling via libvirtd, QEMU will listen on a port number in the range 49152->49216 for a connection from the source host. This error messages shows that the source host was unable to connect to the target host. You've not provided any useful information about your setup, so I'd have to guess that probably you have firewall rules on the target host that are blocking the source host access to the TCP port in question.

Comment: Think you very much